# How to set sample weights in torch loss functions?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, loss-function

i know that `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=?)` the parameter "weight" is meant to balance the unbalance between samples from different classes, it's the parameter for classes, and it has the length of the number of classes.

So if i want to set the weight of different samples when calculating the loss, which has the lenth of the number of samples, what should i do?
ps: just like "sample_weight" in `keras.Sequential.fit(sample_weight=?)`

tried using `torch.nn.Parameter()` but seemed useless;
expecting some solutions plz.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with sample weights in your cross entropy loss you need to do it adhoc like:

```py
entropy_loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
loss = entropy_loss(output, target)
loss = (loss*sample_weights).mean()
loss.backward()
```

see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/per-class-and-per-sample-weighting/25530/4

This assumes that your sample weights are normalized btw.

Answer (score 1):

using sample_weight every step in learning

```
loss = criterion(outputs, batch_targets)
weighted_loss = (loss * sample_weight).mean()
```

Comment: helped a lot ! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone else might meet the same problem like i do, here is my solution:

> class My_CrossEntropy(torch.nn.Module):
> def **init**(self):
> super().**init**()

```
def forward(self, x, y, sample_weight):
    x = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
    y = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(y,num_classes = 8)
    y = y * sample_weight.reshape(-1, 1)
    loss = -torch.mean(torch.sum(y * x, dim=1), dim=0)
    return loss
```